# Using python tkinter library, how to write a function that checks if a textbox is checked?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to see what checkbox are checked and write a if/else function to do stuff. The number of check boxes depends on the number of topics I parse into the program and create a checkbox for each item.

I added:
chk_state = IntVar()

But this is only good if you are using one checkbox.

I am using a list to generate all my checkboxes:

Which generates these variables for each checkbox:

```
'chk0', 'chk1', 'chk2', 'chk3', 'chk4', 'chk5', 'chk6', 'chk7', 'chk8', 'chk9', 'chk10', 'chk11', 'chk12', 'chk13', 'chk14', 'chk15', 'chk16', 'chk17', 'chk18', 'chk19', 'chk20', 'chk21', 'chk22', 'chk23', 'chk24']
```

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from reader import openit
import sys

data = openit(sys.argv[1])
window = Tk()

#set size of window
window.geometry('850x400')

window.title("Chose Your ROS Topic" )
lbl = Label(window, text="Topics", font=("Arial Bold", 25))
lbl.grid(column=0,row=0)


#check checkbox value boolean
chk_state = IntVar()
#chk_state.set(0) #uncheck
#chk_state.set(1) #checked


#Looping through list and adding each one as a checked button
counter = 0

selected_list = []

for x in data.split(","):
   # global selected_list
    #print(x)
    #print(counter)
    name = "chk" + str(counter)

    # appends each checkbox name to a list 
    selected_list.append(name)


    name = Checkbutton(window, text='%s' % x , font=(15), onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=chk_state)
    if counter == 0:
        name.grid(column=1, row=1)
        #print('only for counter 0')
    else:
        name.grid(column=1, row=1+counter -1)
        #print("the rest")


    counter += 1

#After selecting all the topics you want to graph
def topics_selected():
    #messagebox.showinfo('Topics picked', 'graphing all your checked topics')
    #for topics in 
    if chk_state.get():
        print("some checked topics")
    else:
        print("Nothing is checked")



# Adding input tkinter textbox
txt = Entry(window,width=10)
txt.grid(column=1,row=0)

# Function that changes buttond
def inputcheck():
    res = "Topics picked " + txt.get()
    lbl.configure(text = res)

def clicked():
    lbl.configure(text="Parser was clicked, checking rosbag")

# Adding button widget
btn = Button(window, text="ROS topic parser", bg="orange", fg="black", command=topics_selected)
btn.grid(column=2, row=1)


#Create a checkbox
#chk = Checkbutton(window, text='Choose')
#chk.grid(column=0, row=4)


window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
    #print(data)
```

I want to be able to add whatever was selected to a list and push that list to another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a tkinter variable for each `Checkbutton`. Right now all you `Checkbutton` shares the same variable `chk_state`.

To make this work, simply move your definition of `IntVar` inside the for loop:

```
...

selected_list = {} #use a dict to store name/IntVar pair; can use a list also

for num, x in enumerate(data.split(",")): #use enumerate to get a num count
    chk_state = IntVar() #create a new IntVar in each iteration
    selected_list[num] = chk_state #save name/IntVar pair
    name = Checkbutton(window, text='%s' % x , font=(15), onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=chk_state)
    if num == 0:
        name.grid(column=1, row=1)
    else:
        name.grid(column=1, row=1+num-1)

#After selecting all the topics you want to graph
def topics_selected():
    if any(s.get() for s in selected_list.values()): #check if any checkbutton is checked
        print ("some checked topics")
        print ([s.get() for s in selected_list.values()])
    else:
        print("Nothing is checked")
```

Comment: Hero! 
Thanks Henry, so that method works!
How would go by displaying the selected checkbox as the string associated with it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the list of names like `chk1,chk3` for the checked buttons?

Comment: The list i'm using has various topics for example: Imudata, linearacc, angularvelocity,....  The text for each checkbox is what I want to return back to a list

Comment: You can use the list comprehension `[k for k,v in selected_list.items() if v.get()]` for that.

Comment: That's what I currently have working, Im trying to get the text string from the selected Checkbutton. For example, if chk21 is selected i want to print out "AngularVelocity"

Comment: Then don't use name as key - use a `int` instead. Then you can use the int to index/slice your list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tk.BooleanVar` for each of your check boxes, and set their values inside a for loop.
Keeping the variables in a list allows you to pass the selection to a function.

```
import tkinter as tk


DEFAULTS = [True, False, False, False]

def display_selected_options(options, values):

    for option, value in zip(options, values):
        print(f'{option}: {value.get()}')

def create_option_selectors(frame, options, option_variables) -> None:
    for idx, option in enumerate(options):
        option_variables[idx].set(DEFAULTS[idx])
        tk.Checkbutton(frame,
                       variable=option_variables[idx],
                       onvalue=True,
                       offvalue=False,
                       text=option,
                       ).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root = tk.Tk()

options = ['chk0', 'chk1', 'chk2', 'chk3']
option_variables = [tk.BooleanVar(root) for _ in range(len(options))]

frame = tk.Frame(root)
create_option_selectors(frame, options, option_variables)
frame.pack()

display_options = tk.Button(root, text='validate', command=lambda options=options, 
                            values=option_variables: display_selected_options(options, values))
display_options.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Alternatively, you could use a dictionary to store the `option -> value` pairs: